# Unit testing form submission which calls component method

Tags: forms, angular, unit-testing, validation

I'm referring to this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9RQqbz4msxgagsipQDpl?p=preview) which demonstrates unit testing form submission in Angular 2/4. If I understand the code correctly, the test validates that the form submits correctly and that the submission eventually (through a spy) calls `this.formSubmit.emit();`.

Why can't the test validate that the component's method of `doFormSubmit` was also called?

I would like the test (and my own form tests) to validate (in the same expectation) the form submission and the component method.

I see other people's tests that test for direct component's method is correctly called without the form AND I see tests like this which get the correct end result but doesn't validate the exact method called. But I don't see any tests that do both.

Is there some async/fakeasync/tick issue that I'm not seeing that would prevent that test?

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="doFormSubmit()">
  <div>
    <div class="clearfix m-b-1">
      <label class="form-control-static" for="reviewContent" i18n>l.product.show.reviewForm.content</label>
      <div>
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          id="reviewContent"
          name="content"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="model.content"
          #content="ngModel"
        ></textarea> {{model.content}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="clearfix m-b-1">
      <label class="form-control-static" for="reviewRating" i18n>l.product.show.reviewForm.rating</label>
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control l-number-input"
          id="reviewRating"
          name="rating"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="model.rating"
          #rating="ngModel"
        />{{model.rating}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
      [disabled]="!form.form.valid"
      i18n
    >l.product.show.reviewForm.submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
{{doFormSubmitCalled}}
```

```ts
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'home-comp',
  templateUrl: `app/test.component.html`
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input()
  public model: any;
  doFormSubmitCalled = false;

  @Output()
  public formSubmit = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public doFormSubmit() {
    //alert.log("doFormSubmit called");
    this.formSubmit.emit();
    this.doFormSubmitCalled = true;
  }
}
```

```ts
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick, async, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

function newEvent(eventName: string, bubbles = false, cancelable = false) {
    let evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  // MUST be 'CustomEvent'
    evt.initCustomEvent(eventName, bubbles, cancelable, null);
    return evt;
}

describe('ProductShowReviewFormComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let comp: TestComponent;
    let submitSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    // SO: spy on component's method
    let componentMethodSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    let contentInput: HTMLTextAreaElement;
    let ratingInput: HTMLInputElement;
    let form: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed
            .configureTestingModule({
                imports: [FormsModule],
                declarations: [TestComponent],
            })
            .compileComponents()
            ;
    }));

    beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        submitSpy = spyOn(comp.formSubmit, 'emit');

        contentInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#reviewContent')).nativeElement;
        ratingInput = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#reviewRating')).nativeElement;
        form = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));

        // SO: component's method spy - EDIT: MUST CALL THROUGH
        componentMethodSpy = spyOn(component, 'doFormSubmit').and.callThrough();

        comp.model = { content: '', rating: '' };

        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick();
    }));

    it('should modify message', fakeAsync(() => {
        const expectedContent = 'The longest content.';
        const expectedRating = '4';

        contentInput.value = expectedContent;
        contentInput.dispatchEvent(newEvent('input'));

        ratingInput.value = expectedRating;
        ratingInput.dispatchEvent(newEvent('input'));

        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick();

        form.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);

        expect(submitSpy.calls.any()).toBe(true);
        expect(comp.model.content).toBe(expectedContent);
        expect(comp.model.rating.toString()).toBe(expectedRating);

        // SO: was the Component's method called
        expect(componentMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

Comment: `doFormSubmit` is an *implementation detail* - you *could* test it gets called, but then you'd be spying on the class under test (which is an anti-pattern) and you're testing the implementation rather than the behaviour (which makes the tests unnecessarily brittle).

Comment: I understand your philosophical issue with the code, and I totally agree,... but what is the technical reason it doesn't work. That is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: There isn't one. Are you saying you've tried it and it didn't? Then show a [mcve] of that.

Comment: I forked & added a spy to the Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/hSoXsdYvcLY3XXrFSYQl?p=preview. The test now fails because the method wasn't called but I think it should have been. Where am I going wrong in my thinking or code?

Comment: Fixing the obvious errors (wrong names, spy doesn't call through) that test *does* pass.

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked. I thought the .and.callThrough() part wasn't needed but know i know. I'll fix the code.